# How do I target the next element in css?

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is it possible to identify the div just below the div class? If so, what would I use to do it?

```
<div class="img-wrap">
<div></div> <---------------- This
<div class="img-wrap">
<div></div> <---------------- This
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="img-wrap">
<div></div> <---------------- This
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `+`, the adjacent sibling selector:

```
div.img-wrap + div
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Curt. I'll credit you for this when the time expires.

Comment: Me either, but it works like a charm! Thanks again, Curt. What is this called? I'd like to know more about it

Comment: @NaN it's called direct sibling selector (or something like that), it targets only 1 element (the right after/next sibling), another kind of sibling selector is general sibling selector using the `~` sign, it targets all the next siblings (all the previous ones are not included).

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks for that. I thought maybe it was a descendant or something like that. I still don't know what the difference is between a descendant, child and sibling.

Comment: @NaN siblings have the same **direct** parent, while a descendant is contained by some ancestor (which may be the direct parent).

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. Thank you for explaining that. CSS has certainly evolved over the years. I was a tables guy for most of that time and absolutely hated CSS. Today, I love it. I am truly in awe at what styles can be applied using little to no code.

Comment: Can this be used the opposite way to select the previous element with a `-` `div.img-wrap - div {}` ?

Comment: this is a very usefull URL: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I'm going there now